# PySpark - avoid data on driver node?

Tags: pyspark

I am new to Spark and I am trying to understand how to write my operations so that they can be performed in a distributed fashion, as opposed to collecting massive datasets onto the driver node.

I need to perform a seasonality decomposition on time series data using the package https://pypi.org/project/statsmodels/. The function `seasonal_decompose` in particular operates on array-like data. How can I run this function on all of the data in a column, without having to first collect the column as a plain Python array on the driver node?

```
from statsmodels.api.tsa import seasonal_decompose

# df is a PySpark dataframe
data = df.select(collect_list('metric')).first()[0]
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(data, model=model, extrapolate_trend='freq', period=period)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases why you would want to distribute your operations using Spark:

1. You have a single large dataset on which you want to perform your analysis, e.g. your result would be **one** [result object](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html) for all of your data points. To solve this case you would need a distributed version of your analysis algorithm and [seasonal_decompose](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html) does not support a distributed analysis. So you are a bit out of luck here.
2. Your data can be split into many smaller datasets (for example it can be split by year, location, use case, ...) so that each part is small enough to be processed onto a node in your Spark cluster and you want all parts be processed in parallel. Each part would result in a specific result object. To solve this case you can split the dataframe into partitions and then use [mapPartitions](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-mappartitions/). Within `mapPartitions` you would process the chunks of your data like you would do it in an undistributed environment.